# Sublimetext cycle through method signatures using keyboard shortcut

Tags: typescript, sublimetext3, intellisense

I'm using SublimeText on a TypeScript project.  I'm trying to find the keyboard shortcut for cycling through the method signatures of a method.  At the moment it shows me the current method signature and I have to click on the location showed in the image with the mouse to cycle through the rest.  If I simply use the cursor keys it goes to the next line instead of cycling through the other signatures.  Is there any keyboard shortcut I can use for this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using the [Microsoft TypeScript package](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/TypeScript) for this, according to the README file you want <kbd>Alt+Up</kbd> and <kbd>Alt+Down</kbd> for this:

[image: key bindings]